# sbt testOnly behavior difference in 0.13.x and 1.x

Tags: sbt

In the following project
https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver,
we recently upgraded from 0.13.12 to 1.1.6.

In 0.13.12 we used to do `sbt "testOnly *JobServerSpec"` and tests cases for the specific class used to run but with 1.1.6, it is not the case anymore.

To reproduce the issue, 
NOTE: If you get a `Not in Gzip format` exception, then in the project root, execute `rm -rf **/target`

1. clone the project, currently it is using 1.1.6.
2. `git checkout d7e231ea4ee9981e49b411d09f132e396c901b98` will switch to a point before 1.1.6 was introduce
3. Execute sbt "testOnly *JobServerSpec", tests should be running
4. `git checkout master` to switch back to version with sbt 1.1.6
5. Execute sbt "testOnly *JobServerSpec"
6. It should not run any tests.